# Rails & RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rmagick

I've been doing some cool stuff with rmagick on my rails app. I tried starting up my project with 'rails server' and I got this error. I believe I have imagemagick and rmagick installed so I don't know why I see this error.

```
/Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/lib/paperclip_processors/cropper.rb:1
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:46
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:45:in `each'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:45
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/railtie.rb:1
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/devinross14/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/vendor/plugins/paperclip/rails/init.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/plugin.rb:81
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/config.ru:3
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/devinross14/Documents/Philo/philo/config.ru:1
```

Comment: On Which OS are you working on?

Comment: Run command: ruby -rRMagick -e "puts Magick::Long_version" #what is returned?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662977/require-rmagick-not-working

Comment: For that command I get 'ruby: no such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your environment.rb

```
config.gem "rmagick", :lib => "RMagick"
```

Comment: Ah good. In my case I use Rails 2.3 with latest Ruby EE and CentOS 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try `gem install rmagick`? What does that give you?

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.1...

No definition for Magick_colors

No definition for Magick_fonts

No definition for Magick_init_formats

No definition for Magick_limit_resource

No definition for Magick_set_cache_threshold

No definition for Magick_set_log_event_mask

No definition for Magick_set_log_format

No definition for Image_initialize

No definition for Image_combine

Comment: That is the response I get from sudo gem install rmagick. Is this good?

Comment: Hum but that means rmagick is installed, did you try on the console: irb and then in the ruby console type require 'rmagick'

Comment: I can't even get rails to boot because of this so how can I do irb?

Comment: The error message I posted in the question occurs because of "rails server"

Comment: Irb is the ruby console, no rails involved. Just type `irb` on your terminal and then do `require 'rmagick'`. What does that give you?